# Building a MySQL server which processor to choose

Tags: mysql, central-processing-unit

I am building a new MySQL server and I have choice between these two processors:

Intel Xeon 5675

AMD Opteron 4284

I don't know which one should I choose? The load on the server will be an average of 80 millions insert/month. There is a huge difference between the price of each processor, but everything else will be the same concerning disk and ram. So I am not sure choosing for the price with AMD or will I really loose a lot of performance not going with Intel.

Thank you!

Comment: You should explain your requirements in more detail. Even a ordinary desktop/laptop CPU from a few years ago will handle a few thousand Mysql inserts per second. This is already much higher than you are looking for, but it depends: what if every inert is 1MB? Will you be loading 80M records once a month only? And whatever your requirements may be, you should try and benchmark the hardware against your application and workload. Because every application/workload is different. Depending on your workload, it could run out that more RAM is better for you than a better CPU.

Comment: Inserting is easy, selecting is the tricky part. Do you have lots of selects and complex database structure?

Comment: We have an avg lenght of 100 bytes per row. We estimated the disk space to be 9 to 12GB each month, but we have only half of our clients using our service yet. We think this will double the amount of insert/month. 
For sure we do selects for reporting, but we are not building live report on the data. Reports are based on the previous day and are built in a separate table as a static record. It is not a really complex schema yet.
The true problem is to keep up the insert rate the faster we can.

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites because of their very limited lifespan. See [Q and A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Comment: Choose Intel. Because I said so.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your disk setup, it is likely the bottleneck will fall under the disks before the CPU. At least in my experience, I could never utilize an 8-core processor on my MySQL server as the disk I/O filled up before even 20% CPU usage.

Unless you have a really fast disk array I would go with the cheaper one.

Comment: Disk will be 10K RPM SAS 6Gbps, but as I said in comment down this answer RAM will be 128GB. I hope that mostly every transaction will be done in RAM.

Comment: Gotcha. If you are truly handling an average of that many records it's a toss-up... you will likely get by on the AMD processor, but all-to0 many times has that been the wrong way to go. If you can afford to get the best, with a slew of that many requests -- get the big guns :)

Answer (score -1):

80M insert/month = 140 insert/second (20 working days, 8 worked hours). MySQL won't fit. So the processor question is very secondary.

From a pure CPU viewpoint, take the Opteron. The Xeon won't make any significant difference for this kind of workload.

Comment: MySQL wont fit?

Comment: This service is 24/7 and we have for sure peak hours where we get more queries but I would say the avg is about 30-60 insert/sec. Concerning the RAM we are planning to put 128GB, so for now it is possible to hold all the database in ram.

Comment: It's entirely possible for MySQL to do 140 inserts per second.